# How can I write this code more efficiently?

Tags: python, coding-efficiency

I feel like this code is excessive - how can it be shorter? I am a beginner so bear with me.

[The problem statement is this (from Automate the Boring stuff)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxjiE.png)

And my code:

```
#printtable() function - will take string list and display in rjustified table

tabledata = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
def printtable():
    colwidths = [0] * len(tabledata)
    strlen = 0

#find parameter for rjust

    for i in range(len(tabledata)):
        for k in range(len(tabledata[i])):
            wordlength = (len(tabledata[i][k]))
            if wordlength > strlen:
                colwidths[i] = wordlength
            strlen = wordlength
    maxword = max(colwidths)

#print as table : 'invert'
    x=0
    while x<int(len(tabledata[0])):
        for i in range(len(tabledata)):
            print(tabledata[i][x].rjust(maxword, ' '), end=''),
        x+=1
        print('\n')

printtable()
```

In general, how can I start to learn to code more efficiently? I was thinking I could start flowcharting ahead of time - since usually I just start writing and change stuff around on the spot. I feel like all my code is ugly, so any tips are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This should be in: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
import six

tabledata = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
def printtable():
    widths = []

    for row in tabledata:
        widths.append(max(*map(len,row)))

    inverted = map(list, six.moves.zip_longest(*tabledata, fillvalue=' '))

    for row in inverted:
        for j,word in enumerate(row):
            w = widths[j]
            l = len(word)
            print ' '*(w-l)+word+' ',
        print
```

Just reduced the inverting part. Also the print ' '*(w-l) is for the spaces at the right. You can also try doing some centre alignment as well here just for fun.

Also to answer your question, you need to practise a lot and understand all of python's data structures like lists especially list comprehensions, map, lambdas,* operator etc. You can see I've used them in plenty in my answer and always try to make your code as 'pythonic' as possible :-P

Also, when iterating lists always use `for a in arr:` or `for i,a in enumerate(arr)` instead if `i in range()`. It looks a lot better